# Software para criar templates

Tags: html, layout, template

Passei a programar em linguagens WEB a alguns anos. Faço mais o Server-side completo e alterações no front-side como javascript, JQuery, Angular, html. Mais tenho dificuldades em criar templates para sites já que o que vem para mim já e os templates feitos.

Procurei sobre o assunto e vi que usavam muito o Adobe Fireworks mais que agora foi descontinuado. Vi muito também sobre Dreamweaver, Photoshop e fiquei com dúvidas.

Qual melhor software usado atualmente para criar os templates?

Comment: Rapaz como vc é do back-end eu entendo, mas tu ta bem desatualizado. Tem uns 5 anos que ninguém mais usa Fireworks, tampouco Dreamweaver. Se vc quer desenhar as telas, montar o layout, enfim, recomendo: Photoshop ou Illustrator(entrou no lugar do Fireworks) ambos da Adobe, também outros que são muitos utilizados são Sketch e Invision para prototipação e layouts.

Comment: Agora se vc quer desenvolver telas com código tem o Adobe Muse e tem tbm o Pingendo que vc clica e arrasta e assim vai montando as telas conforme a necessidade. Ainda se vc quer usar só código aí tem vários editores de texto: Brackets, SublimeText, Visual Studio Code, Atom, Notepad++, RubyMine, PhpStorm.

Comment: @Leandro Sim, uso Sublime Text para editor de código. Mais tenho dificuldade em criar o layout do site. Preciso mesmo um caminho para começar a estudar a criar as telas. Já que pra mim somente chega as paginas prontas só faltando eu criar as funções em JavaScript, Angular, etc da pagina e ai termino com o back.

Comment: Se você está com dificuldade em dar andamento em algo já pronto no front-end, o mais sensato(na minha opinião) já que vc já manja de código, e cair em cima do html e css...

Comment: @williamCoqueiro sabe que tu faz (na minha humilde opinião), baixa o Pingendo que já vem com os templates prontos do bootstrap, aí vc só arrasta e monta as telas do jeito que tu quiser. Isto vai te dar uma boa base para começar a montar as telas, o que é normal, pois td mundo de back-end tem muita dificuldade em design. Ele já monta um arquivo html e css tbm, aí ou vc edita o html e css no próprio Pingendo ou no SublimeText.

Comment: @MagicHat Então minha dificuldade e no design, quero passar a fazer essa parte do design. E complicado depender muito do pessoal do design as vezes.

Comment: É mano, o melhor caminho para mim é na raiz, `html` e `css`, depois se parte pra um framework que te deixe confortável...

Comment: @Leandro Amigo estou anotando tudo aqui o que estão me passando. Está servindo de grande ajuda. Em relação a editar html e css eu já sei muito.

Comment: @Leandro Você faz design?

Comment: @WilliamCoqueiro Sou front-end, mas desenvolvo layouts sim.

Comment: @Leandro Você costuma usar estes softwares para produção ou faz direto pelo editor de textos?

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro sim vou direto pela codificação mesmo, só quando tenho que mostrar pro cliente um protótipo aí eu monto o layout  e depois codifico.

Comment: @Leandro Você acha que então estarei indo para o caminho errado? Vi que citou acima a dificuldade dos back-end com design, e realmente e verdade, ficamos muitos presos no back sem podermos praticar no front. Mais para mim html e css não e problema. O problema talvez seria a criatividade minha em relação está parte.

Comment: @williamCoqueiro cara na minha opinião designer é uma área de humanas diferente da programação que é exatas, mas, nada que ninguém não possa aprender e desenvolver. Acho que se vc quer criar as telas, começe acompanhando blogs, publicações sobre design web que tem muitos pela internet, vão te dar idéias e conceitos.

Comment: Já que vc acha que tem demanda para vc se aprofundar no design seria uma boa tbm se vc pudesse fazer um curso, nessas escolas profissionalizantes mesmo, um curso de designer gráfico seria o ideal, pois vc aprenderia a mexer com as ferramentas citadas, Illustrator, Photoshop, Corel, algumas mais avançadas dependendo da escola como Invision ou Axure. Aí vc ve se pra vc vale a pena investir.

Comment: Ok, Obrigado. vou dar uma olhada. Foi de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Willian, com certeza de todos que você citou o mais apropriado seria o Photoshop, porem você terá que ter uma noção boa de designer, mas lembrando que ele só cria o visual do seu site, o back-end animações e transições você terá que fazer manual.

O Dreamweaver alem de criar o visual, apesar de ser um programa bem limitado ele cria o back do código porem muito poluído e tem algumas ferramentas prontas para aplicações mas nada de outro mundo.

O ideal seria você testar e ver qual você se adapta melhor, e qual consegue suprir suas necessidades.

Comment: Acho que estas a fazer confusão entre back-end e front-end

Comment: @MagicHat Estão negativando minha pergunta, poderia me dizer se eu disse alguma besteira para que eu possa corrigir a pergunta?

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro geralmente uma pergunta fora de escopo recebe negativo, eu até dei um +1 pq acho que -1 já é suficiente... É normal, mas vale você dar uma consultada na [help], para entender o motivo...